# F#: error FS0193: Specified method is not supported

Tags: recursion, f#

I'm really new in F#. So I'm trying just find length of list.
But when I call len or len2 functions F# says "Specified method is not supported" and I've no idea why

```ml
let rec len x = 
    if List.isEmpty x then 0
    else 1 + len (List.tail x)

let rec len2 = function
    | [] -> 0
    | _::tl -> 1 + len2 tl
```

edit: I use VS Code (ubuntu 19.10), Ionide-fsharp extension

[image: demo]

Comment: I get no such error and see no reason why you should either. But you don't even show the calls, so the error is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Any chance you are running this code on Mono in `fsharpi`? If so, what version of Mono are you using?

Comment: The `len2` function does not call any methods, so it cannot yield that error.

Comment: @TomasPetricek yea, you're right! I moved to new laptop lately and didn't install f# correctly. I think, I've not called sudo apt-get install fsharp. Thanks, all working now.

Comment: @DmitryGashko Glad you managed to fix this. It's a very confusing error message!

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't install f# correctly, so I finished the installation and it works now.